# Adding footer text SVG or PDF

Tags: php, pdf, svg, inkscape

I'm working in a small **PHP script** that transform a SVG file into PDF using InkScape command-line.

The thing is I need to add a footer text with an Order #. This needs to be via command-line because it is automatically called by the script.

I'm doesn't worried of the text format or font. I Just need to enlarge the canvas height a little and add the text with white background.

I've looked after several PDF and SVG command line editors, to do add the text before or after the conversion, with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

to traverse the document before it is rendered to the client, find the bottom of the page (append to the SVG tag) and append the footer dom nodes before it ends processing on the server side.

```
<svg>...<g><text>This is a footer</text></g></svg>
```

Comment: Sounds like an option. Thanks!